# Spark: how to write dataframe to S3 efficiently

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to figure out which is the best way to write data to [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/getting-started/?trkCampaign=acq_paid_search_brand&sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_EMEA&sc_publisher=Google&sc_category=Storage&sc_country=EMEA&sc_geo=EMEA&sc_outcome=acq&sc_detail=amazon%20s3&sc_content=%7Bad%20group%7D&sc_matchtype=e&sc_segment=468762436981&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CBrand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CStorage%7CS3%7CEMEA%7CEN%7CSitelink%7Cxx%7CEU&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!468762436981!e!!g!!amazon%20s3&ef_id=Cj0KCQjwreT8BRDTARIsAJLI0KIHbuWKjFaOThmGoKRh4_wCExjsfBbdjcDvkGDn7dIyTcccYS3MM9kaAiCvEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!468762436981!e!!g!!amazon%20s3) using [(Py)Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter).

It seems I have no problem in reading from S3 bucket, but when I need to write it is really slow.

I've started the spark shell like so (including the `hadoop-aws` package):

```sh
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<key_id> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret_key> pyspark --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0
```

This is the sample application

```py
# Load several csv files from S3 to a Dataframe (no problems here)
df = spark.read.csv(path='s3a://mybucket/data/*.csv', sep=',')
df.show()

# Some processing
result_df = do_some_processing(df)
result_df.cache()
result_df.show()

# Write to S3
result_df.write.partitionBy('my_column').csv(path='s3a://mybucket/output', sep=',')  # This is really slow
```

When I try to write to S3, I get the following warning:

```
20/10/28 15:34:02 WARN AbstractS3ACommitterFactory: Using standard FileOutputCommitter to commit work. This is slow and potentially unsafe.
```

Is there any setting I should change to have efficient write to S3? As now it is really slow, it took about 10 min to write 100 small files to S3.

Comment: what about `s3://`?

Comment: @Lamanus that seems to be only supported on EMR cluster which ships with EMRFS (modified Hadoop file system by AWS). Is it possible somehow to use EMRFS locally for test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out you have to manually specify the committer (otherwise the default one will be used, which isn't optimized for S3):

```py
result_df \
    .write \
    .partitionBy('my_column') \
    .option('fs.s3a.committer.name', 'partitioned') \
    .option('fs.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode', 'replace') \
    .option("fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer", "bytebuffer") \ # Buffer in memory instead of disk, potentially faster but more memory intensive
    .mode('overwrite') \
    .csv(path='s3a://mybucket/output', sep=',')
```

Relevant documentation can be found here:

- [hadoop-aws](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html)
- [hadoop-aws-committers](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html)

Comment: FWIW, that s3a.fast.upload.buffer option isn't relevant through the s3a committers. Tasks write to file://, and when the files are uploaded to s3 via multipart puts, the file is streamed in the PUT/POST direct to S3 without going through the s3a code (i.e the AWS SDK transfer manager does the work).

Comment: Also, for the staging committer, you must have a cluster FS, "spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFs". That's needed to get the output of tasks to the job committer. If you use file:// and you don't have a shared NFS mount, then you may end up with empty output